How to troubleshoot why the count of messageconversion is high for the kafka produce and fetch network requests
I am seeing very high count for kafka_network_requestmetrics_messageconversionstimems_count metrics for both produce and fetch request.
Kafka version being used is 3.6.1
log.message.format.version=3.0-IV1
inter.broker.protocol.version=3.6-IV2
All the topics are using latest default message.format.version i.e 3.0-IV1 (same as brokers log.message.format.version)
also all the kafka clients are updated to the latest version. How to check why the message conversion is happening
Have checked the message.format.version of broker and all the topics
There are different types of kafka client i.e producers and consumers are using different languages like java, go, python etc. Have verified that all the kafka client are using 3 or higher version (3.X version)
Expectation : there should not be any message conversion happening
